# How to get the anchor tag text in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I need to get the anchor tag text I clicked on in code behind. The anchor tag doesn't have id. There are a lot of such a tags on page. After clicking tag, the text should be the title of the new page.

It looks as following:

```
<a href="Actions.aspx?ActionTopTypeID=10">Hello world</a>
```

I need to get "Hello world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get this in code behind directly.

As you are clicking on `<a>` it will issue GET request and you can send your data to server either in a query string or cookie. Better approach would be sending it in a Query string.

```
<a href="Action.aspx?ActionTopTypeId=10" onclick="SetData(this)">Hello</a>

function SetData(obj){
 var obj.href=obj.href+"&Text"=obj.innerHTML;
}
```

in code behind

```
string text=Request.QueryString("Text");
```

Comment: here where you are setting hidden field value ? you just modifying the href with querystring right?